# Intel GMA 4500MHD flickering in opengl

Tags: intel-graphics, integrated-graphics, opengl

I have an application that uses OpenGL for its display.  When this application is run on a laptop with an Intel GMA 4500MHD on Windows XP the OpenGL content appears to flicker/shudder between 2 frames.

I have experienced the exact same problem when running this application on nVidia Quadro FX hardware, however with nVidia the problem can be corrected by disabling the "Unified Back Buffer" (UBB) feature in the driver.

Does anybody know how I can disable the corresponding feature in the Intel driver?

Answer (score 0):

The UBB is not a feature of all graphics drivers, it's a feature of the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for the early 2009 driver for this card. I have the same card and I remember seeing alot more options in the openGL settings then the options im getting in the new panel of this driver.